# adding UI to cell swift

Tags: swift

I have an application where I am working with dynamic UI and I am apple to condition the type of UI to add to a cell. The proplem now is when the UI is added, it is uneditable, eg, if a uitextfield is added, I cannot add any input or edit it and if a datepicker is added, it cannot be edited. any help is welcome. below is an attachment of my code

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cellModel = elements[indexPath.row]
        let cellIdentifier = cellModel.unique_id
//            cellModel.type.rawValue
        let customCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellIdentifier!, for: indexPath) as! CustomElementCell

        customCell.configure(withModel: cellModel)

        return customCell as! UITableViewCell
    }
```

// my cell

```
func configureUI(type: String, placeholder: String) {

        let type = TypeView.typeCell(type: type, placeholder: placeholder)
        switch type {

        case .text:
            let tf = DefaultTextField()
            tf.placeholder = placeholder
            self.contentView.addSubview(tf)
            log("THE LOG test")
        case .embeddedphoto:
            let tf = DefaultTextField()
            tf.placeholder = placeholder
            tf.keyboardType = .numberPad
            log("THE LOG embeddedphoto")
        case .formattednumeric:
            let tf = DefaultTextField()
            tf.placeholder = placeholder
            log("THE LOG formattednumeric")
        case .datetime:
            let dp = UIDatePicker()
            self.contentView.addSubview(dp)
            log("THE LOG datetime")
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1- You should create a cell for each dynamic type and register it

2- For your current implementation you need to add constraints to added elements and clear the cell to avoid dequeuing  problems

Comment: I have to cast it `as! UITableViewCell` because this is customelementcell `protocol CustomElementCell: class {
    func configure(withModel: ElementsModel)
}`

Comment: you don't have to use a protocol here do you ?

Comment: yes because `CustomElementCell` is dynamic and the count changes too

Comment: do you add constraints ?

Comment: frame/autolayout is the base behind focus